# Quando usar #if DEBUG e quando usar Conditional("DEBUG ") ou if (Debugger.IsAttached)?

Tags: c#, .net, estilo-de-codificação, debug

Por que usar:

```
#if DEBUG
    public void Metodo() {}
#endif
```

ou

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void Metodo() {}
```

ou

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) {
    public void Metodo() {}
}
```

Comment: O terceiro vai dar um erro de sintaxe. Pra declarar métodos locais, não pode ter modificadores de acesso. Além disso, a expressão `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` só irá testar se o thread está em um processo em depuração, ou seja, nem sempre poderá chegar, mesmo se for compilado com `-c Debug`.

Comment: Verdade, eu nem tinha me atentado a isso :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A primeira grande diferença que podemos notar é que só o primeiro omite o código por completo se não for um *build* com *debug* (considerando que tudo está sendo feito corretamente). O atributo condicional emite código normalmente, e a compilação decide se o método será chamado ou não, sem custo de processamento.

Apesar de ser mais eficiente em espaço, geralmente você não quer usar a diretiva em um código de função, o mais comum é ter apenas um trecho do método, ou escolha entre fazer uma linha ou outra.

Pensa bem, se o método deixar de existir, a chamada dará erro, nem compilará. Então provavelmente só funcionaria se tivesse um `#else` com a implementação em branco. Porém, neste caso a chamada aconteceria apesar de nada executar. Se não tiver uma otimização do JITter (se ele estiver presente), isso é ineficiência pior ainda (não conte com otimização). Mas se em vez de um método em branco precise de outra implementação aí é bem diferente e poderia ser útil, mas neste caso talvez deveria ter apenas um código de declaração do método e dentro dele ter corpos diferentes de acordo com a variável `DEBUG` existir ou não.

O último caso é todo resolvido em tempo de execução, portanto é ineficiente em tempo de processamento e espaço, raramente faz sentido para uso geral em aplicações que não são de teste ou tem uma atividade específica de *debugging*, ele não foi criado para resolver algo entre tipos de *releases*. Você tem a informação antes do tempo de execução, quase sempre preferirá usar isso em vez de deixar para a último momento. Nem dá para usar pela declaração, teria que usar uma outra forma dentro do método. Considerei que iria usar dentro do corpo, o que torna um caso diferente. E aqui independe da variável de compilação, então pode dar outro resultado.

Em resumo, pra imitar o ChatGPT :) (eu testei, a resposta foi quase inútil, ele só disse o que cada um faz, não se posiciona, nem insistindo), para métodos, ainda que consuma espaço no executável por emitir código CIL, o atributo é melhor em quase todas as situações, a não ser que possa controlar a chamada também. A diretiva pode servir para constantes, trechos de códigos ou algo mais pontual, o que deveria ser mais comum de usar. Não achei um motivo tão claro para fazer diferente em código que realmente vai para produção.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).